# Assign an initial value to radio button as unchecked

Tags: php, html

There's an answered question titled "Assign an initial value to radio button as checked". I need to know how to do the same, but with the value of "unchecked". I ask this because I need to pass the "checked" or "unchecked" value as a PHP variable, dependant on a condition, but passing checked="", still returns checked. If setting "unchecked" is not done with checked="", how is it done? Here is my code:

```
         if($status=='Billable'){
               $status1 = 'checked';
               $status2 = '';
                           }else{
                                    $status1 = '';
                                    $status2 = 'checked';                                        
                                }
```

html:

```
    <input type='radio' name='status' checked='".$status1."' value='Billable'>

    <input type='radio' name='status' checked='".$status2."' value='Not Billable'>
```

Comment: @Juan That's not how boolean attributes work in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

With boolean attributes, there's no way to provide the attribute with a false value -- either the attribute is there or it's not.

Rather than return the value to assign to the attribute, return the entire attribute.

```
if($status=='Billable'){
    $status1 = 'checked=checked';
    $status2 = '';
}else{
    $status1 = '';
    $status2 = 'checked=checked';                                        
}
```

Then when generating the HTML you do:

```
<input type='radio' name='status' $status1 value='Billable'>
<input type='radio' name='status' $status2 value='Not Billable'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should REMOVE the checked attribute from the DOM object.

`$input->removeAttribute("checked");`

Also, this functionality shouldn't require any PHP code since both radio inputs have the same `name` property and only one can be selected at a time.